# JavaScript variable scope inside forEach loop

Tags: javascript, scope

In the code below there is callback function used with forEach loop going over returned results. Is variable 'error' inside forEach loop and 'error' in callback same variables ?

```
session.getAll(options, function (error, varbinds) {
    varbinds.forEach(function (vb) {
        if (error) 
            console.log('getALL Fail ');
        else              
            console.log(vb.value);            
    });
});
```

Comment: unless the inner function scope introduces a new 'error' variable, it will be the same.

Comment: You don't have any other `error` variable defined, so the answer is **yes**.

Comment: As others have said yes if it isn't re-defined with a `var` in the loop, however a `forEach` loop cannot be aborted. So checking the error should be done in the callback before you get into the loop. If you need to check in the loop for whatever reason a different looping method should be employed.

Comment: @irom I realize this is a few years old now, but I just got an upvote and, when I checked it out, I saw no accepted answer here. Did we manage to help enough to check this off?

Answer (score 12):

**Yes, it is the same variable.**

I'm not sure how much you know. So, I'm going to explain in detail. Scoping in JavaScript is at the function level*. Think of function definitions as points on a tree. Each point on the tree is a scope. When using a variable, you can only use what is at your current scope and anything available to ancestors going up to the top (global scope). Here are a few rules & examples that may help you better understand:

***UPDATE: ES6 `const` and `let` are block-level**

**Inner functions have access to outer function-level variables**

```
function a() {
    var a = 4;

    function b() {
        alert(a); /* a = 4 */
    }
}
```

**Parameters are defined at the same scope as if they were defined one line below**

```
function a(a) {
    // variable "a" is at same scope as the example above

    function b() {
        alert(a);
    }
}
```

**Variables in adjacent functions are not accessible**

Function a() is the parent. b() and c() are its children. Those children cannot access each other's variables.

```
function a() {

    function b() {
        var aValue = 2;
    }

    function c() {
        alert(aValue); /* "aValue" is undefined here */
    }
}
```

**Location of function definition is what counts**

This returns 5 if you run `main();`:

```
function getValue(returnFunc) {
    var a = 7;
    alert(returnFunc());
}

function main() {
    var a = 5;
    getValue(function() { return a; }); // anonymous function becomes "returnFunc"
}
```

**Lastly, variable overriding**

```
(function getValue() {
    var a = 5;

    (function () {
        var a = 7;
        alert(a);
    })();

    alert(a);
})();
```

I tried to avoid using self-invoking functions/IIFEs for these examples but I just couldn't help myself on this last one. It's the easiest way, I think. Run this and you'll get 7, then 5. But, if you exclude "var" on that inner "a"...

```
(function getValue() {
    var a = 5;

    (function () {
        a = 7;
        alert(a);
    })();

    alert(a);
})();
```

You'll get 7, 7. This is because "var" creates a new space in memory. Also, if there is a name conflict with something in a higher scope, it gets overridden as a different variable (despite having the same name).

For some more examples, please see: [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: If instead of using `var` if `let` where used, are the variables defined with `let` available in the callback?

Comment: @PatS Yes, if `let` or `const` were used, they are available in the anonymous functions below in most of my examples here. But, if `let` or `const` were wrapped by an `if` statement, `for` loop, or some other type of block and the function was defined outside of that block, then it would not be available. Does that help?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's the same variable, it would change if you define another `error` variable inside the scope of the forEach callback by using the `var` keyword:

```
session.getAll(options, function (error, varbinds) {
    varbinds.forEach(function (vb) {
        if (error) //Same error as the error parameter above
            console.log('getALL Fail ');
        else              
            console.log(vb.value);            
    });
});

session.getAll(options, function (error, varbinds) {
    varbinds.forEach(function (vb) {
        var error = false; //New error for this closure.
        if (error) 
            console.log('getALL Fail ');
        else              
            console.log(vb.value);            
    });
});
```